# Querying SelectToken with JSONPath

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I need to pass in a variable to get all tokens which match. For some reason I can't get it to recognize the value of variable I am passing. I'm hoping someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong...

For example,

When I hardcode a valid id as below, I get the 6 records that match that id. This is the expected outcome.

```
JObject results = JObject.Parse(sampleJson);

                        // add each task to the list "tasks"
                        foreach (var task in tasks)
                        {
                             IEnumerable<JToken> taskNotes = results.SelectTokens("$.tasknote[?(@.taskid == '8155423')]");

                        }
```

If I try to pass the task id from the loop (the first one in the loop is the same as the hardcoded one), it gives the correct number of matches for the first two iterations and then no matches for any of the iterations after that, even though I know there are matches.

```
                        JObject results = JObject.Parse(sampleJson);




                        // add each task to the list "tasks"
                        foreach (var task in tasks)
                        {
                             IEnumerable<JToken> taskNotes = results.SelectTokens("$.tasknote[?(@.taskid == '"+ task.Id +"')]");

                        }
```

Comment: 2 things you could try, first: could you try without the ' quotation? For example, `@.taskid == '"+ task.Id +"'` becomes `@.taskid == "+ task.Id +"` and also try escaping the single quote: `@.taskid == \\'"+ task.Id +"\\'`.

Comment: Can you share a [mcve] that reproduces the problem, including a JSON sample?